# SQL Server 2005: T-SQL to query when a database was last restored?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is it possible to do so using T-SQL alone? What query would you write against the system tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the field restore_date in the restorehistory table in the msdb database.

[MSDN - restorehistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187408.aspx)

```
SELECT
MAX(restore_date)
FROM
msdb.dbo.restorehistory
WHERE destination_database_name = 'SomeDB'
```